# Prove that $\lim_{}{x_{n}}=L\iff L=x_{1}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }{(x_{k+1}-x_{k})}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence of real numbers. Show that $\lim_{}{x_{n}}=L\iff L=x_{1}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }{(x_{k+1}-x_{k})}$.

I've tried using the fact that the sequence $(x_{n})$ can be expressed as a series of partial sums, taking for example:

\begin{equation}
a_{1}=x_{1}\\
a_{n+1}=x_{n+1}-x_{n}\\
\Rightarrow a_{1}+\cdots+a_{n}=x_{1}+(x_{2}-x_{1})+\cdots+(x_{n+1}-x_{n})=x_{n}
\end{equation}

But I dont' know where to go next to prove the $\Rightarrow $ and $\Leftarrow $ statements. I'm thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

As you almost wrote,
$s_n
=x_{1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{(x_{k+1}-x_{k})}
=x_{n}
$
and since
$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n
=\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n
=L
$.

Since
$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n
$
is the definition of
$x_1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(x_{k+1}-x_k)
$,
you are done.